# Nice equality involving summation, factorials, and $e$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion

I came across this nice equality that I don't know how to solve:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-j}j^{j-1}}{j!}=1.$$

I'm guessing the first step is to write out the Taylor series, which gives a double sum of:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-j)^n}{n!}\right)j^{j-1}}{j!}$$

and maybe this can be seen to be the product of two other functions in Taylor form, which I can't see. Also, I know this can be solved by elementary methods, so a "simple" solution would be nice. Help is appreciated!

Comment: This is an equality, not an inequality.

Comment: $x$ should read $j$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. For $|x|< 1/e$, the power series 
$$T(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{j^{j-1}}{j!}\,x^j,$$
which is the [exponential generating function for rooted labeled trees](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/trees.pdf),
satisfies the identity
$$T(x)=xe^{T(x)}.$$
Now you need to show that $T(1/e)=1$.

Answer (score 4):

By [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), the principal branch of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), defined through $W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$, has the following expansion near the origin:
$$ W(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}x^n\tag{1} $$
In particular,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n! e^{n}} = -W\left(-\frac{1}{e}\right) = \color{red}{1}\tag{2} $$
since the function $x\cdot e^x$ equals $-\frac{1}{e}$ at $x=-1$, from which $W\left(-\frac{1}{e}\right)=-1$.

Comment: This is very interesting ! In spite of my love for Lambert function, I missed it. Thanks for posting this nice solution.

Comment: This is the answer I was trying to find (+1) I had proven $(1)$ when [this question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22953413#22953413) was asked in chat.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an approximate value of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-n}\, n^{(n-1)}}{n!}$$ using [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) of the factorial.

Since $$n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \left(1 +\frac{1}{12n}+\frac{1}{288n^2} - \frac{139}{51840n^3} -\frac{571}{2488320n^4}+ \cdots \right)$$ that, for the time being we can write, $$a_n=\frac{e^{-n}\, n^{(n-1)}}{n!}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } n^{3/2} P_n}$$ where $P_n$ is the term in brackets.

Now, using long division (or, better, Taylor series) $$\frac{1}{P_n}=1-\frac{1}{12 n}+\frac{1}{288 n^2}+\frac{139}{51840 n^3}+\frac{571}{311040
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ which makes $$a_n\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\frac 1 {n^{3/2}} -\frac 1 {12} \frac 1 {n^{5/2}}+\frac1 {288} \frac 1 {n^{7/2}}+\frac{139} {51840} \frac 1 {n^{9/2}}+\frac{571} {311040} \frac 1 {n^{11/2}} \right)+\cdots$$ Now summation $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\frac{\zeta
   \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)}{12}+\frac{\zeta
   \left(\frac{7}{2}\right)}{288}+\frac{139 \zeta
   \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)}{51840}+\frac{571 \zeta
   \left(\frac{11}{2}\right)}{311040} \right)\approx 1.00103$$ Adding more terms will make the result closer and closer to $1$.

**Edit**

If, instead of Stirling, we use Ramanujan's famous factorial approximation, 
$$n!\approx\sqrt{\pi}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\root\LARGE{6}\of{8n^3+4n^2+n+\frac{1}{30}}$$ and expand the radical as a Taylor series, we should arrive to
$$a_n\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\frac{\zeta
   \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)}{12}+\frac{\zeta
   \left(\frac{7}{2}\right)}{288}+\frac{139 \zeta
   \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)}{51840}-\frac{2947 \zeta
   \left(\frac{11}{2}\right)}{2488320} \right)\approx 0.99990$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\expo{-j}j^{\, j - 1} \over j!} & =
\sum_{j\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\expo{-j} \over j!}\,\,\,
\overbrace{\pars{j - 1}!
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\expo{\, jz} \over z^{\, j}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
^{\ds{=\ j^{\, j - 1}}}\,\,\, =\,\,\,
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,\sum_{j\ =\ 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{\expo{z - 1}/z}^{\, j} \over j}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
-\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,
\ln\pars{1 - {\expo{z - 1} \over z}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
-1 -
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,
\ln\pars{z - \expo{z - 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\end{align}
The equation $\ds{z - \expo{z - 1} = 0}$ has infinite solutions$^{\large\S}$.
One of them is obviously $\ds{z = 1}$ and the remaining ones have
$\ds{\verts{z} > 1}$.
$$\bbox[#ffd,10px,border:0.5px groove navy]
{\begin{array}{l}
{\large\S}:~\mbox{They are evaluated by}\ \texttt{Mathematica}\ \mbox{as}\
\texttt{ProductLog[k,-1/e]}\ \mbox{with}\,\,\, k \in \mathbb{Z}\
\end{array}}
$$
It reduces the complex integration to:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\expo{-j}j^{\, j - 1} \over j!} & =
-1\ -\,\,\, \overbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,
\ln\pars{z - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{=\ -2}} = \bbx{\ds{1}}
\end{align}